# Formatting GregorianCalendar in EL with JSTL/fmt

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, date-format

I'm having a small problem with a JSP page. I'm using Stripes as framework but this should not be that relevant.
Basically I have a bean that returns via a getter a date in the form of a `GregorianCalendar`.
I have to display this date in JSP. When I try:

```
<fmt:formatDate type="both" dateStyle="full" value="${myObject.itsGregorian}">
```

I get an exception saying that he is unable to convert `GregorianCalendar` to `Date`.

I understand that `fmt:formatDate` formats a `Date` object and not a `GregorianCalendar`, but is there a way to turn around it?
Since this is an assignment and I've got a pre-coded Bean I'm not allowed to touch the bean, so I can't transform its getter for the date to return a `Date`.

How can I solve this the best?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It indeed only supports [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). You need to call [`Calendar#getTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) to get it out the calendar.

```
<fmt:formatDate type="both" dateStyle="full" value="${myObject.itsGregorian.time}">
```

Comment: Just set a more specific style than `full`. Read the `DateFormat` javadoc for examples: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html You can also use the `pattern` attribute. Read the `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc for examples: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html If you stucks, just press `Ask Question` on right top :)